# Java: Combining multiple predicates

Tags: java, collections, predicate

In Java, is there a short elegant way to combine multiple predicates (Guava Predicate) into one?

Currently, I have some list of predicates:

```
Collection<Predicate<TypeA>> preds = ...;
```

And I have some code that loops through the predicates and returns false if any one of them are false. Is there a one-liner that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: Umm... write a method to do it for you? Now it is a one liner for users!

Comment: nope, that's not what i'm after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Guava, it looks like `Predicates#and` will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Google Guava library](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#and-com.google.common.base.Predicate...-), this is merely Predicates.and(preds).